# SteamedResponse not outputing on flush

Tags: php, symfony, nginx

So I'm working on a script in Symfony PHP where I need to read multiple response streams in, and then stream them back out to the client. The relevant endpoints sit behind nginx proxies.

Reading streams in:

```
    $fileHandle = fopen('php://temp', 'w+');

    // Implements StreamableInterface
    foreach ($responses as $response) {
        try {
            $stream = $response->toStream();
            while (!feof($stream)) {
                fwrite($fileHandle, fread($stream, 4096));
            }
        } catch (TransportExceptionInterface $e) {
            continue;
        }
        unset($response);
    }
```

I am catching a TransportException here, primarily in case a 504 Gateway Timeout is received from Nginx. In that case, we will just progress like no exception was thrown. I also tried to change this bit over to stream_copy_to_stream, but was getting similar results

The problem comes when trying to serve this file back to the client. There are some steps missing in between, but this is the general gist:

```
        rewind($fileHandle);

        $streamedResponse = new StreamedResponse();
        $streamedResponse->setCallback(function() use ($fileHandle) {
            while(!feof($fileHandle)) {
                echo fread($fileHandle, 1024);
                // ob_flush();
                flush();
            }
            fclose($fileHandle);
        });

        $streamedResponse->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/force-download');
        $streamedResponse->headers->set(
            'Content-Disposition',
            'attachment; filename=' . $fileName
        );
        $streamedResponse->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/csv; charset=UTF-8');
        $streamedResponse->headers->set('X-Accel-Buffering', 'no');
```

If I just echo / dump out the fread line, I can see everything just fine in Symfony's profiler, or the tab which made the request. However, as soon as I call flush(), I do not get served any file, and I can no longer view any output from the script, no entry in the profiler, no dumps, no logs, almost like the process has just completely stopped.

I have only been able to replicate this when a 504 is thrown earlier in the workflow, but I can't really see what bearing this would have on the response sent back to the client. I have also tried different combinations of ob_start, and ob_flush, and nothing seems to fix this issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that you must first read all responses before sending the streamed response. It is eating a lot of memory.
A better approach would be to read and write directly to the output from the callback function.
You can use `php://output` and `stream_copy_to_stream` instead of reading parts of the stream as you mentioned.

```php
// To be adapt to your project

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\HeaderUtils; // Used later

$streamedResponse = new StreamedResponse();
$streamedResponse->setCallback(function() use ($fileHandle, $responses) {
    $fileHandle = fopen('php://output', 'wb');
    foreach ($responses as $response) {
        try {
            $stream = $response->toStream();
            stream_copy_to_stream($stream, $fileHandle);
        } catch (TransportExceptionInterface $e) {
            continue;
        }
    }
});

// Useless as redeclared below $streamedResponse->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/force-download');
$disposition = HeaderUtils::makeDisposition( HeaderUtils::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT, $fileName);
$streamedResponse->headers->set('Content-Disposition', $disposition);
$streamedResponse->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/csv; charset=UTF-8');
$streamedResponse->headers->set('X-Accel-Buffering', 'no');

return $streamedResponse;
```